# How to implement UIPopover kind of functionality in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipopover

In my app i have a PieChart which has certain divisions denoting different areas or region. Every partition has its own color but there are like 10 partitions and i want to show which part shows which region. It would have been an easy task with iPad as we have UIPopover but here in iPhone i don't know what to do, so i thought if there is any suggestion any one can make. I want to PieChart be visible with the detail about each partition.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will find many popover controllers http://cocoacontrols.com/search?q=popover

Comment: None of them seems perfect to display some information on iPhone.

Comment: I think zpopover will do your work and they all are open source codes so you can modify one for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a UIview with tableview and imageview inside it .

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own custom Popover type control by making a UIView then adding the desired elements to it and making it as a subview or keeping this view hidden from the start then making it visible on button press.