# How to make a facebook like box in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

does anyone of you know how to make a box like this in xcode:
[image]
I saw a Box like this in many apps and now want to implent it into my Project!
Is there any Framework or somerhing for it?

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Any book on iOS will give you the answer.

Comment: Essentially that's a UIPopoverController-lookalike for the iPhone. There are [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798550/uipopovercontroller-for-iphone) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987218/uipopover-for-iphone-or-is-it-fake) [existing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742283/how-to-implement-uipopover-kind-of-functionality-in-iphone) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742283/how-to-implement-uipopover-kind-of-functionality-in-iphone) that give options on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There are custom controls available in [cocoa controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=popover)

[Check out this](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=popover)
[fppopover](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fppopover)

Comment: Thats what I searched for! Thanks guys!

Comment: @YannickKrohn If you prefer the Github link to FPPopover: https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom popoverController which is made for iPhone
http://code4app.com/ios/Popover-View-in-iPhone/4fa931bd06f6e78d0f000000

Comment: Do have a link to the English version?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve it without using any library. Take a look at this basic tutorial: http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/presenting-a-popover-in-ipad/